# Whats a good word for somebody holding back sobs?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am in a *roleplay* and want to express my character ***holding back sobs out of fear of being seen as weak*** but don't have a **word** for it

Comment: They can be ***stifling sobs***.   Don’t know a single word for the whole thing.

Comment: thank you :D
(words i need to comment-)

Comment: ***Choked back** the tears*. But not a word...

Answer (score 0):

A general word, although it applies to more than just not crying, is [**stoic**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stoic#h2):

> [Merriam-Webster]
> **2** : not affected by or showing passion or feeling
> *especially* : firmly restraining response to pain or distress
>     // a *stoic* indifference to cold

So:

> Although I was sad and felt like crying, I remained *stoic*.